# Flutters Android Java source shows errors in IntelliJ

Tags: flutter

I created a default Flutter project and opened it in IntelliJ. The IOS part works. On the Android site I get the following errors when I try to build the android module in IntelliJ. It seems to work if I open the android module in Android Studio alone (by using the menu item 'Open Android module in Android Studio'). Is this expected ?

```
Error:(3, 18) java: package android.os does not exist
Error:(5, 22) java: package io.flutter.app does not exist
Error:(8, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class FlutterActivity
Error:(10, 27) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Bundle
  location: class com.yourcompany.helloflutter.MainActivity
Error:(9, 3) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(11, 5) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.yourcompany.helloflutter.MainActivity
/Users/roger/Documents/hello_flutter/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
Error:(3, 32) java: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
Error:(9, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PluginRegistry
```

Comment: What is __flutter doctor__ telling?

Comment: flutter doctor says:  No issues found!

Comment: That works OK for me. (I normally create the app inside IDEA using the File/New/Project/Flutter wizard, but just tried opening a `flutter create projectname` using File/Open and selecting the *projectname* folder.) Could you try creating a new project the File/New/Project/Flutter way? Which version of Dart and Flutter plugins do you have? Post a screenshot of Project Structure/Modules/*projectname*_android, and Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK. In IDEA, does Tools/Android/AVD Manager work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the full project in Android Studio rather than just Android Module. Also install the Dart & Flutter Plugin in Android studio. It will help you to work properly.

Comment: The OP asks how to get a Flutter project to work in IntelliJ IDEA, rather than Android Studio - which is totally possible, though can be tricky. I never open Android Studio any more (though have to have it installed still, of course), and work exclusive in IDEA, which seems to be the OP's goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
First, make sure **Project Structure - Problems** related to the project all gone.
Second, mark the following directories like the following picture at **Project Structure - Modules**.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li7Tt.png)

Third, set the project SDK to Android SDK at **Project Structure - Project**. This may be changed with Java SDK after build, but you don't have to concern about it unless you run into some trouble.